# How to calculate the sum of each day from my excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A       B       C       D       E
    SKU     Date    Sale    Date    Sum of Sale
    b0001   01-Apr  1000    01-Apr
    b0002   01-Apr  2500    02-Apr
    b0003   01-Apr  5000    03-Apr
    b0004   02-Apr  3500    04-Apr
    b0005   02-Apr  3500    05-Apr
    b0006   07-Apr  2900    06-Apr
    b0007   07-Apr  3000    07-Apr
    b0008   08-Apr  2500    08-Apr
    b0009   08-Apr  7500    09-Apr
    b0010   08-Apr  6500    10-Apr
    b0011   10-Apr  7000    11-Apr
    b0012   10-Apr  8000    12-Apr

What is the formula for summarizing the sale of each day of the month? Without using Pivot. Thanks in advance. Sorry, I'm not a programmer, Just trying to help my sister with her boutique shop.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried SUMIF() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMIF` to do this - `=SUMIF(B:B,E2,C:C)`

[image]